# how can i utilize google search on my own website in China?

Tags: php, google-api, google-search

As you know,google is blocked in China. Now I want to put a php search function in my website for user to search by a keyword and get result from my website and more important, from both two search engines, google and Baidu. I have already get done with baidu. But I can get done with google.

Here I have an idea: since my hosting is in mainland China, I can get another vps(like hostus) in USA, when some one search in my webisite, I can let program send a command to this second vps and let it do the specified research using google and send right back the result to my local vps.

is it possible? I know google has a way to identify robots. do you have any great idea to solve this? I want my user search a keyword and get result page on my website showing a website search, a baidu search and a dreaming gooogle search.

Thank you!